# How can I make this replace operation with a wildcard in Sublime Text?

Tags: find-and-replace, sublime-text-3, sublime-text-2

I have 100 objects like that:

```
{
  "_id": "5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb09",
  "category": "Vel aliquid quas",
  "title": "Incidunt incidunt quae ut et in provident ut est rerum."
},
{
  "_id": "5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb09",
  "category": "Some text",
  "title": "Some title"
{
```

In Sublime Text 3, how do I replace that with:

```
{
  "_id": "5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb09",
  "category": "5e99e61b3b7733f59053e49a,
  "title": "Incidunt incidunt quae ut et in provident ut est rerum."
},
{
  "_id": "5eb45c2738ae2549000ddb09",
  "category": "5e99e61b3b7733f59053e49a",
  "title": "Some title"
{
```

Answer (score -1):

- Find: `category":\s+"(.*?)`
- Replace: `"category": "your text"`

Comment: Welcome on the SuperUser! Please elaborate your answer, it should be useful also for visitors.